# Administrative processing

Tags: usa

My wife went for immigrant visa interview about 2 weeks ago. She said the VO didn't ask for or check any of her documents, she was asked about 3 questions which she answered, then the VO returned her passport and gave her a white form that says you case need further administrative processing, and that she will be contacted within 2 weeks. It's been 2 weeks already and we didn't hear from the consulate. What can we do at this point?

Answer (score 0):

You can always check the status of your visa application in [CEAC](https://ceac.state.gov/CEACStatTracker/Status.aspx).

Current guidance from the State Department is to [wait at least 180 days](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/administrative-processing-information.html) before inquiring with the consulate about the status of your application.

> Except in cases of emergency travel (i.e. serious illnesses, injuries, or deaths in your immediate family), before making inquiries about status of administrative processing, applicants should wait at least 180 days from the date of interview or submission of supplemental documents, whichever is later.